# How to cite correctly in a document with quotes in several languages using csquotes?

Tags: punctuation, tufte, quoting, csquotes

I'm working on a document written primarily in Spanish, but contains many quotes between quotation marks, multiple nested. It also contains text blocks that I usually compose with the environments `quote` and `quotation` (if more than one paragraph).

I want to use `csquotes` because I think a great package for this. I have reviewed the documentation, however no examples to help me understand how many things are used, and I have not used enough.

As you will see in the MWE I'm using the `Tufte-book` class because I like the layout and the notes to the margins as in the Renaissance. I clarify because I think there may be problems between the package and class.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{marginfix}

%\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}  
%\addbibresource{socialBib.bib}  
%\usepackage{hyphenat}  
\usepackage[style=german,french,mexican]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. ``Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate `velit' 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur''. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim 
id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, seddo eiusmod     
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea  
commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in  
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`

\begin{quote}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod  
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. `Germanum 
requiem [Deutsches Requiem]' Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
\end{quote}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. \sidenote{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
est laborum.}
\end{document}
```

My doubts about `csquotes` are:

1. How I define the style or need a style for each language?
2. If each language that I need to cite with different quotes, how do I
   set it? Since the text is in Spanish and I live in Mexico, normal
   for me is to use the Mexican option with `"`, single quotes `'`,
   French guillemets `«` `»` and would like to use standard German quotation
   marks (low and high).
3. For blocks instead of `quote` or `quotation` environments I think I
   could use `\blockquote`, but sometimes I'll nested notes, and
   sometimes these nested notes will have any word (usually in German).
   How do I set `\blockquote` for it?
4. Do I have to declare explicitly with `babel` (a command that has to
   do I guess) the change of language in the text for proper
   hypehnation or `csquotes` does it?
5. Finally, I'll add references `biblatex` not now, but I don't know if
   it's necessary have some considerations or add an option for this in the
   preamble when loading `csquotes`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer /Ö\ You're right! I forgot to paste the first line in the MWE -_\ Thanks, now is in its place.

Comment: I think it's dubious practice to adapt the quotation mark style to the language of the text that's being quoted. If most of your readers are used to Mexican-Spanish typographic practices, employ them consistently. Your readers will, mostly likely, become either distracted or amused when they encounter a multitude of quotation mark systems.

Comment: @Mico Maybe, we know guillemets because we also read books from other Spanish-speaking countries which are part of its typographic practice. Perhaps the only strange could be German quotation marks, but since quotes are in German and are not too much, I don't think they cause confusion.

Comment: Regarding the `biblatex` question: `biblatex` is very happy if you load `csquotes` (especially if you use `babel`). But normally there is nothing more to be done than loading `csquotes`. Re hyphenation: `\foreignquote` and its derivatives automatically use `babel`'s `\foreignlanguage`, so hyphenation and everything should be fine there (there is also `\hyphenquote` and friends, see §3 of the [`csquotes` doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf))

Comment: As an aside: It is normally preferred to only ask *one specific question* per question, so there can be a proper answer to it.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I know it would have been ideal to specifically ask a question at a time. I tried to be as specific as I could, but I asked in this way because all the questions I have are related to `csquotes` and I think that context is important to get a proper response.